# Class flash.media::CameraRoll could not be found (Flash Builder 4.7)

Tags: flash, air, flash-builder

When I attempt to compile a Flash Professional AIR for Mobile project in **Flash Builder 4.7**, I get this error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.media::CameraRoll could not be found
```

I've asked about this several times on Adobe's forums and never gotten a response.

I also got this error in **4.6**. I don't know if I'm missing something in the FB settings. The project compiles fine in Flash Professional CS6.

Comment: Which Flex SDK are you compiling with? The `CameraRoll` requires the AIR 2.0 SDK... but if you are compiling with the Flex 3.6 SDK that only includes AIR 1.5 ... You can upgrade the AIR SDK that is contained inside the Flex SDK or switch to Flex 4.6.

Comment: I'm using FB 4.7; the default SDK (which I'm using) is 4.6

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm using whatever Flash player/debugger gets called by Flash Builder. Our workstations at work are not connected to a wireless network so I can't debug remotely to profile the app while it's running on the device. Any idea what I could do here?